# Unable to Register IOS device to Mobile First 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

I am able to see the iOS device under devices tab in MF, registered to my application. but pushing a notification fails with the below error:

```
An error occurred while the notification was sent. Internal server error. No devices found.
```

[image: device list]

Upon reviewing IOS code, I noticed the below issue while invoking MFPPush.sharedInstance.registerDevice(nil)

```
Cannot retrieve a valid authorization header for header. Check resource and authorization server configuration.
```

I am using the code from the git [sample](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsSwift). Below is the snippet throwing the error:

```
 @IBAction func registerDevice(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Attempting Device registration with Mobile First")
        WLAuthorizationManager.sharedInstance().obtainAccessToken(forScope: "push.mobileclient") { (token, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Did not recieve an access token from server: " + error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                WLClient.sharedInstance()?.setDeviceDisplayName("White Ipad", withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                    if error == nil{
                        print("device display name is set")
                    }else{
                        print("error setting device name: " + error.debugDescription)
                    }
                })
                print("Recieved the following access token value: " + (token?.value ?? "no token"))
                MFPPush.sharedInstance().registerDevice(nil) { (response, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.enableButtons()
                        self.showAlert("Registered successfully with Mobile First")
                        print(response?.description ?? "")
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert("Registration failed with Mobile First.  Error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Mobile First Config: I have followed the documentation and configured the UserLogin security check from the sample git project and have removed scope to push.mobileclient under security.

Reading the OAuth Security in MF, i understand the that token is necessary to access resources, but I am unable to figure out how to attach the token in registerDevice().

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you haven't configured Push Notifications properly in MobileFirst Server.

- Make sure that you have added `push.mobileclient` scope in Security tab of your application. If you are not using any security check, you can add scope like below.
  [image]
- Check whether your application is configured valid iOS provisioning profile enabled with Push Capability
- Make sure that you have uploaded valid sandbox/production certificates in Push tab of your particular app in MFP Operations Console. 
  More details : [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#apple-push-notifications-service)
- Make sure your app is enabled Push Capability in the project setting and also check you sending device token to MF Server using `MFPPush.sharedInstance().sendDeviceToken(deviceToken)` API in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method of `AppDelegate` file
  -

Comment: Hi Vittal, i have done all the three steps. I have also tested the push notifications from a sample pusher application and verified that the APNS setup is working.

Comment: @Ramakrishna What you receiving in the call back of `registerDevice` API

Comment: HI @Vittal, the register Device  method is failing with com.ibm.mfp.server.core.shared.MFPRESTException: 400; headers=[]; body={ errorCode=INVALID_CLIENT_ID errorMsg=Invalid client ID.} . From what i read, when i am calling registerDevice, the HTTP request is failing the Introspect Filter, it is unable to find the client id in the HTTP request

Comment: @Ramakrishna, Uninstall the app from device and Reinstall fresh application. You shouldn't face this issue.

Comment: no luck with that, But i found out something today, push notifications were working when i  installed on a new version of Mobile First. I noticed MF on my client systems  have not been upgraded and i am suspecting a possible bug with version mismatch in Client-SDK and Mobile First Server (MF server version(Product version: 8.0.0.00-20180417-0743)

Comment: Try with latest version of MF Server and MF SDK

Comment: its the last resort as the client has multiple applications running on the current server, raised a IBM PMR, awaiting reply.